# simple delete query using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a delete query from HTML using PHP:

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" action="" >
    ID<input type="text" name="x" />
    <input type="submit"  value="DELETE" name="del"/>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
$db = mysql_select_db("smap", $connection) or die ("Couldn't select database");
if(isset($_POST['del'])) {
    $a = $_POST['x'];
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE syracuseone WHERE ID ='$a'";)
    if(mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "deleted";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    } 
}
?>
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: x

Any assistance from stack?

Comment: Add `if(isset($_POST['x']))`

Comment: Your POST parameter is not set.

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` keyword in your query & the semicolon should be outside the brackets: `$sql = mysql_query("DELETE syracuseone WHERE ID ='$a'";)`.

Comment: +1 @Korikulum I was just going to make a mention of that.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your post value was not passed to the next page, you can do something like this `$a = isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST["a"] : 0;`

Take a look, here is it's usage:

```
<form method="POST" action="" >
    ID<input type="text" name="x" />
    <input type="submit"  value="DELETE" name="del"/>
</form>

<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't connect to server");
$db         = mysql_select_db("smap", $connection) or die("Couldn't select database");
if(isset($_POST['del'])){
    $a   = isset($_POST['x']) ? $_POST["a"] : 0;
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM syracuseone WHERE ID ='$a'");
    if(mysql_query($sql)){
        echo "deleted";
    }else{
        echo "fail";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the diff betwn if(isset($_POST['x']))  and if(isset($_POST['del'])) i i thought i was coding based on the submit buttom anyway i am not that very good in php

Comment: `isset($_POST['x'])` checks the `x` input, `isset($_POST['del'])` checks the `del` input.

Comment: Actually when using this form when del is set x should be set as well. Can you show me how $_POST looks like? `print_r($_POST)`